# Cron to securely upload file to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cron, ubuntu-server

I'm building an Ubuntu based headless server for a medical clinic which comprises of a medical patients record app writing to a mysql file.
I currently have a cron job backing up the mysql file to .zip and this takes place daily at midnight.

I'm trying to figure out the best way have an automated cron command that would take this zip file securely (this being medical records - we're not in the US, so are not affected by HIPAA) across to Amazon S3.

Would really appreciate some help on this, pls.

Answer (score 1):

The **[AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)** can upload files to Amazon S3 across an SSL connection. Very easy to run from a cron job.

For added security, you might want to add a password to your zip file and use the `--sse` CLI option for
enabling **Server-Side Encryption** that will encrypt the file at-rest in S3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar, here's what I came up with:

```
DIR="/srv/my_project/db_backups"
FILENAME="${DIR}/my_project-`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`.sql.gz"
CRONLOG="${DIR}/cron.log"
SQLCNF="${DIR}/my_project.cnf"

mysqldump --defaults-file="${SQLCNF}" --routines --user=root --triggers --single-transaction my_project | gzip -9 > "${FILENAME}" 2>> "${CRONLOG}" && /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp --sse "${FILENAME}" s3://my-bucklet 2>&1 | tee -a "${CRONLOG}"
```

`/usr/local/bin/aws` is the tool [John recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27894436/65387).